# Error with UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I have this code for send images on tweet. When I try the app, the picker works well but it doesn't grab the image. What's wrong?

```
- (IBAction)sendImageTweet:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [tweetViewController addImage:(UIImage *)imageData];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the constant, not an NSString and the key.

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm new in iOS dev... How can I use the constant and the key?